# Can not install miniconda on Raspberry Pi 4 B

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I just installed the latest raspberry OS "2022-04-04-raspios-bullseye-arm64-lite.img.xz". Then I want to install miniconda. I downloaded the latest "Miniconda3 Linux-aarch64 64-bit" and running

```
bash Miniconda3-py39_4.12.0-Linux-aarch64.sh
```

After answer 'yes'

```
Please answer 'yes' or 'no':'
>>> yes

Miniconda3 will now be installed into this location:
/home/pi/miniconda3

  - Press ENTER to confirm the location
  - Press CTRL-C to abort the installation
  - Or specify a different location below

[/home/pi/miniconda3] >>>
PREFIX=/home/pi/miniconda3
Unpacking payload ...
Miniconda3-py39_4.12.0-Linux-aarch64.sh: line 413:  1590 Illegal instruction     "$CONDA_EXEC" constructor --prefix "$PREFIX" --extract-conda-pkgs
```

I got "1590 Illegal instruction" error, and conda is not installed at all. So how can I correctly install miniconda on raspberry OS?

Comment: i think that aarch64 is for Intel or AMD processors

Comment: @jsotola So there is no raspberry version for miniconda?

Comment: Please check this link https://gist.github.com/simoncos/a7ce35babeaf73f512be24135c0fbafb and this and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39371772/how-to-install-anaconda-on-raspberry-pi-3-model-b

Answer (score 3):

You need to download Miniconda3-py39_4.9.2-Linux-aarch64.sh.

`sudo wget http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-py39_4.9.2-Linux-aarch64.sh`

`sudo /bin/bash Miniconda3-py39_4.9.2-Linux-aarch64.sh`

Do not upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I originally tried following miniconda docs [instructions](https://docs.conda.io/projects/miniconda/en/latest/) adapted for the Pi

```
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-aarch64.sh -O ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh
bash ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh -b -u -p ~/miniconda3
```

but got:

```
PREFIX=/home/<USER>/miniconda3
Unpacking payload ...
/home/<USER>/miniconda3/miniconda.sh: line 359:  5736 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) "$CONDA_EXEC" constructor --prefix "$PREFIX" --extract-conda-pkgs
```

then performed

```
wget http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-py310_23.5.2-0-Linux-aarch64.sh -O ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh
bash ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh -b -u -p ~/miniconda3
```

but got

```
/home/<USER>/miniconda3/miniconda.sh: line 359:  8024 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) "$CONDA_EXEC" constructor --prefix "$PREFIX" --extract-conda-pkgs
```

So I switched back to the version py39 as suggested above

> https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/139651/157251

```
sudo wget http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-py39_4.9.2-Linux-aarch64.sh
```

And it worked ! So it appears that only the python 3.9 version of the release is functional on a Raspberry Pi4 (on Ubuntu 23.04, kernel Version Linux 6.2.0-1004-raspi,4Gb RAM).

Thanks again @john-breiland

Answer (score 0):

As [suggested](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/10723#issuecomment-881961846), you could also try miniforge [releases](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases). Worked for me in rp3 using debian.